# How do you select a varchar2 field in the format of 'HH24:MI:SSxFF6' as an INTERVAL HOUR TO SECOND(6)?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

The following query succeeds:

```
SELECT INTERVAL '00:00:00.000000' HOUR TO SECOND(6)
FROM DUAL;
```

The following fails:

```
SELECT INTERVAL time_field HOUR TO SECOND(6) -- time_field is a VARCHAR2(15)
FROM some_table;
```

w/ the following error:

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

How do I fix my second query to pull back an HOUR TO SECOND INTERVAL?

When I try:

```
SELECT cast(time_field AS INTERVAL HOUR TO SECOND(6))
FROM some_table
```

I get the following:

```
ORA-00963: unsupported interval type
```

TEST SETUP:

```
CREATE TABLE some_table (
   time_field VARCHAR2(50)
);

INSERT ALL
INTO some_table (time_field) VALUES ('10:00:00.000000')
INTO some_table (time_field) VALUES ('12:00:00.000000')
INTO some_table (time_field) VALUES ('15:00:00.000000')
INTO some_table (time_field) VALUES ('17:00:00.000000')
INTO some_table (time_field) VALUES ('20:00:00.000000')
INTO some_table (time_field) VALUES (NULL)
SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`TO_DSINTERVAL` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions202.htm); example here using a CTE to replicate your table:

```
WITH some_table AS (SELECT '00:00:00.000000' AS time_field FROM dual)
SELECT TO_DSINTERVAL('0 ' || time_field)
FROM some_table;

TO_DSINTERVAL('0'||TIME_FIELD)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
+000000000 00:00:00.000000000
```

Note that to make the format something the function recognises, you have to supply a 'days' part, hence the prepending of the dummy `'0 '` string.

Your fixed-value query returns a slightly different format (or at least displays slightly differently; [interval daa types do not have format models](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/sql_elements001.htm#BABBICGH) in quite the same way as dates, so not sure how to express that accurately):

```
SELECT INTERVAL '00:00:00.000000' HOUR TO SECOND(6)
FROM DUAL;

INTERVAL'00:00:00.000000'HOURTOSECOND(6)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
+00 00:00:00.000000
```

To replicate that you can `cast` this if you need to:

```
WITH some_table AS (SELECT '00:00:00.000000' AS time_field FROM dual)
SELECT CAST(TO_DSINTERVAL('0 ' || time_field) AS INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND(6))
FROM some_table;

CAST(TO_DSINTERVAL('0'||TIME_FIELD)ASINTERVALDAYTOSECOND(6))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
+00 00:00:00.000000
```

... or just:

```
WITH some_table AS (SELECT '00:00:00.000000' AS time_field FROM dual)
SELECT CAST('0 ' || time_field AS INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND(6))
FROM some_table;

CAST('0'||TIME_FIELDASINTERVALDAYTOSECOND(6))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
+00 00:00:00.000000
```

... which is pretty much what @catcall first suggested, but this also needs the `'0 '` prepended, or you get an `ORA-01867`. (Or, if you try to use `HOUR TO SECOND`, `ORA-00963`, even with the prepended day value). However, I guess (and it is just a guess, though very slightly educated) that it's doing an implicit `TO_DSINTERVAL` or similar, and I think I'd prefer to use an explicit one so I was sure what's happening. That might just be me, though...

---

Using your sample data I too get an `ORA-01867`, but it's caused by the null value. You can use a `case` to leave that as null in the result:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN time_field IS NULL THEN null
    ELSE CAST('0 ' || time_field AS INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND(6)) END
FROM some_table;

CASEWHENTIME_FIELDISNULLTHENNULLELSECAST('0'||TIME_FIELDASINTERVALDAYTOSECO
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
+00 10:00:00.000000
+00 12:00:00.000000
+00 15:00:00.000000
+00 17:00:00.000000
+00 20:00:00.000000


6 rows selected.
```

Comment: Both solutions get the following error: `ORA-01867: the interval is invalid`

Comment: @scrappythenell - does your `time_field` have exactly the data you had in the fixed-value version? That's what I used. I'll update the answer to show the CTE I was using to test.

Comment: Updated above w/ Table & Data creation script.

Comment: @scrappythenell - I get that error from the `null`; if I omit that row from your `insert all` then it works for me. If you want the query to get `null` if the table column is `null` then you'll need to wrap it in a `decode` or `case` so it doesn't try to convert it, I think?

Answer (score 0):

I'd think this (untested) cast were called for.

```
SELECT cast (time_field as interval hour to second(6))
FROM some_table;
```

Your column will have to be of a type that's compatible with a cast to interval, and it will have to contain data that can be interpreted as an interval.

[Oracle 11g docs for CAST](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions021.htm)

---

Sample code

```
create table test (
  interval_type interval day to second,
  varchar_type varchar2(35) 
);

insert into test values (
  (current_timestamp - to_date(current_date)),
  (current_timestamp - to_date(current_date))
);

select 
  interval_type, 
  varchar_type
from test;

INTERVAL_TYPE                                                                              VARCHAR_TYPE
{"Bytes":[-128,0,0,0,78,95,84,-102,-92,-83,-64],"ShareBytes":null,"Length":11,"Stream":{}} +000000000 18:35:24.000000

select 
  interval_type, 
  cast (varchar_type as interval day to second)
from test;

INTERVAL_TYPE                                                                               CAST(VARCHAR_TYPEASINTERVALDAYTOSECOND)
{"Bytes":[-128,0,0,0,78,95,84,-102,-92,-83,-64],"ShareBytes":null,"Length":11,"Stream":{}}  {"Bytes":[-128,0,0,0,78,95,84,-128,0,0,0],"ShareBytes":null,"Length":11,"Stream":{}}
```

Comment: TIME_FIELD is a VARCHAR2 so that doesn't work for my situation. `ORA-00963: unsupported interval type`

Comment: According to the link, the varchar2 data type is compatible with a cast to interval. But a varchar2 value of 'wibble, wibble' isn't. What do the values in that column look like?

Comment: When I try it I get `ORA-00963: unsupported interval type`

Comment: Hmm. Digging on, it looks like Oracle doesn't support an `interval hour to second`. It does support `interval day to second`.

Comment: @Catcall It still gives the error even with `interval day to second` when using a column from a table.