# Getting invalid interval error in oracle while using DbFunctions Add Minutes Method in entityframework

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I am trying to add minutes to my date column and then use a where clause to compare date.

```
DateTimeOffset offset;
var dto = DateTimeOffset.TryParse(searchTerm, out offset);
var offSettMintutes = (int)offset.Offset.TotalMinutes;
if(!dto)
{
offSettMintutes = 0;
}
var filteredQuery = queryForRequests.Where(item => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(DbFunctions.AddMinutes(item.SUBMIT_DATE, offSettMintutes)) == searchTermDate);
```

It is throwing error saying

> {"ORA-01867: the interval is invalid"}

Comment: using .Equals()

Comment: If we use .Equals() different error was thrown "Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

Comment: see this  - > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376901/how-do-you-select-a-varchar2-field-in-the-format-of-hh24missxff6-as-an-inter

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376901/how-do-you-select-a-varchar2-field-in-the-format-of-hh24missxff6-as-an-inter this link shows how to query it in oracle database. In my case when I query on oracle databse everything is working fine but querying via entity framework is throwing error.

Comment: Same problem here, though I'm getting an {"ORA-00961: bad datetime/interval value"} error using the DbFunctions.AddHours method.  When I extract the raw generated PL/SQL it doesn't run in the db either...so I think there's a bug in the .Add** methods in terms of how it is generating the INTERVAL blocks.